# How to implement Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a big java program made in GUI using netbeans, in which I have many java files. I have used `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` but it doesn't work well for me. What I actually want is that the items get re-sized to full screen that's when I came across this API. I want to know how to implement this API into my program. The problem is that I am a newbie (I make most of the program using Netbeans GUI) and I don't know exactly where should I add the code to make it use this API

Is there a easy way to do it? Which does not require me to make the whole program again?

Comment: Start here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I have seen this page but the thing is that now i cannot go and make the program again... isn't there a easy way to do it???

Comment: will you please tell me the problem in simple words.Try to add JScrollPane in JFrame, then add a JPanel into it , then you can add components into it , and it will be auto scrolled.

Comment: This part "the items get re-sized to full screen", if it means resizing the componenets (i.e make them larger/smaller) then yes you will need to rewrite.  That method, `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`, will only maximize the frame without resizing the componenets.  Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)

Comment: @DonChakkappan I din't get you i am not looking for scroll

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb So what all do i need to rewrite and how? and yah I read the block from the link you said, i did not understand much over there but yah you got it correctly that: what i want is all the components to resize

Comment: Read the first link, if you use a layout it will resolve the issue.  Use BorderLayout

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb But if i just go and select Border Layout in Netbeans it just screws up the look of my whole page :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go through the [Full Exclusive Mode tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html).  All it is is a matter of checking is full screen mode is supported. If it is, then get the screen device and `setFullScreenWindow(...)`. If it's not supported, just use regular windowing.

See this simple example

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FullWindow extends JFrame {
    private boolean isFullScreen = false;
    private GraphicsDevice device;

    public FullWindow(GraphicsDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        initFullScreen();
    }

    private void initFullScreen() {
        isFullScreen = device.isFullScreenSupported();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(isFullScreen);
        setResizable(!isFullScreen);
        if (isFullScreen) {
            // Full-screen mode
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            validate();
        } else {
            // Windowed mode
            this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment
                        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                new FullWindow(device);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know some more things do you mind chatting with more for some minutes?

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: we had talked earlier so you know what code i have i wanted to know where do i put this and also that I tried to email you but maybe that got reflected or what... are you busy these days cauz you said that you were going to help me make the java program in layout so that it works but i couldn't contact you after that. I just wanted to know whether you.....

Comment: Sorry I rarely check my email. And yes I have been busy. If you want to set up a chat I have a little bit of time now